# Laravel Event Mocking

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a test with this code

```
Event::fake();

Queue::fake();

// Fake an order
$order = factory(Order::class)->make();

event(new PaymentWasCompleted($order));

Event::assertDispatched(PaymentWasCompleted::class, function ($e) use ($order) {
    return $e->order->id === $order->id;
});

Queue::assertPushed(GenerateInvoiceJob::class, function ($job) use ($order) {
    return $job->order->id === $order->id;
});
```

My EventServiceProvider looks like this:

```
   protected $listen = [
        \App\Events\PaymentWasCompleted::class => [
            \App\Listeners\GenerateInvoice::class,
        ]
    ];
```

And the GenerateInvoice listener looks like this:

```
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->eventName = 'GenerateInvoice';
    }

 public function handle(PaymentWasCompleted $event)
    {
        // Access the order using $event->order
        $order = $event->order;

        $job = (new GenerateInvoiceJob($order, $this))->onQueue(app('QueueHelper')->getQueueName($this->eventName));
        $this->dispatch($job);
    }
```

I would expect the test to be passing, but it fails with:

> The expected [App\Jobs\GenerateInvoiceJob] job was not pushed.

I am unsure why that is.

I also tried

```
Queue::assertPushedOn(app('QueueHelper')->getQueueName('GenerateInvoice'), GenerateInvoiceJob::class, function ($job) use ($order) {
            return $job->order->id === $order->id;
        });
```

same issue.

Comment: I have same problems. I have no idea how to test events triggering the listeners and I've spent a good amount of time trying. Testing events is easy (with the method you used). Testing handlers is easy, just mock an event and instantiate a listener with it and call `->handle()`. But testing that an event actually triggers the listener - I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I think you will need to have 2 different tests. One just fake the event and in the second one fake queue. The fake will check if the event was triggered and that's about it. It is not interested in whats your expected behaviour is or what action should it trigger

Comment: @devk: Yeah, that I know, but i want to make sure that the listeners are being fired correctly. Very weird.
@usrNotFound: What exactly do you mean? You mean that I should just remove `Event::fake();`if I want to test for the listeners being fired correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After re-reading the docs, it is clear that this is intended behaviour. The docs say

> As an alternative to mocking, you may use the Event facade's fake
>   method to prevent all event listeners from executing.

As described in a comment, I have to create two tests. One for making sure that the event has been fired and contains the expected data and a second one for making sure that the event listeners get fired.

So, first Test:

```
Event::fake();

$order = factory(Order::class)->make();

event(new PaymentWasCompleted($order));

Event::assertDispatched(PaymentWasCompleted::class, function ($e) use ($order) {
    return $e->order->id === $order->id;
});
```

Second test:

```
Queue::fake();

$order = factory(Order::class)->make();

event(new PaymentWasCompleted($order));

Queue::assertPushed(GenerateInvoiceJob::class, function ($job) use ($order) {
    return $job->order->id === $order->id;
});
```

As expected, this tests pass.