# Event assertDispatched fails to assert the events generated inside a loop

Tags: php, laravel, events, phpunit

I have the following code which emits the events inside a loop

```
class FooStatus extends Command
{

    public function __construct(Foo $foo)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {

        FooGroups::query()->whereNull('a_field')
            ->get()
            ->each(static function(FooGroup $fooGroup) {
                dump("inside");
                event(new fooGroupEvent($fooGroup));
            });

    }
}
```

The test is written in the following manner.

```
public function test_foo_event(){
    Event::fake();
    //some code
    (new FooStatus($foo))->handle();
    Event::assertDispatched(fooGroupEvent::class);
}
```

> The expected [App\Events\Foo\FooGroupEvent] event was not
> dispatched. Failed asserting that false is true.

Although the assertion fails my dump() prints in the logs which mean it actually emits the event.
But if I get the event emission outside the loop it asserts true.

Where have I done wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Event Mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321737/laravel-event-mocking)

Comment: Nope, When it's done as mentioned in that it works since the event is not emitted inside a loop. But in my case, it emits many events inside the loop

Comment: Are you sure, because, from the docs: "As an alternative to mocking, you may use the Event facade's fake method to prevent all event listeners from executing."